# How to fix error "OperationFailure: BSON field 'insert.startTransaction' is an unknown field" after trying to insert document during transaction

Tags: python, mongodb, transactions, pymongo

I made replication on my server, because mongoDB permits multi-document transactions only in replication. After that I tried to launch this code:

```
db_client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27000)
col = db_client['test_db']['test_col']
with db_client.start_session() as session:
    with session.start_transaction():
        for i in range(10):
            col.insert_one({'msg': i}, session = session)
            if i == 8:
                raise Exception
```

In my opinion it should write nothing to database because in block `with session.start_transaction():` exception will occur and must be called session.abort_transaction().

But I got error which I can't interpret:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: BSON field 'insert.startTransaction' is an unknown field.
```